# Display record even if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I have this table

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       34       X
B       43       L
A       36       L
```

Now if I query

```
select * from Table1 where col1 in ('A','B','C')
```

I am expecting something like

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       34       X
B       43       L
A       36       L
C       -        -
```

Is it possible ?

P.S: the `-` in row C are just to show that the column is empty.

Comment: what was the result when you tried that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a nested table schema object type:

```
create type T_List1 as table of varchar2(100);
```

And then construct your query as follows:

```
 select s.column_value            as col1
      , nvl(to_char(t.col2), '-') as col2
      , nvl(col3, '-')            as col3
  from Table1 t
 right join table(T_List1('A', 'B', 'C')) s
    on (t.col1 = s.column_value)
```

Example:

```
-- sample of data from your question
with Table1(Col1, Col2, Col3) as(
  select 'A',  34,  'X' from dual union all
  select 'B',  43,  'L' from dual union all
  select 'A',  36,  'L' from dual
)  -- actual query
 select s.column_value            as col1
      , nvl(to_char(t.col2), '-') as col2
      , nvl(col3, '-')            as col3
   from Table1 t
  right join table(T_List1('A', 'B', 'C')) s --< here list your values
     on (t.col1 = s.column_value)            -- as you would using `IN` clause
```

Result:

```
COL1  COL2   COL3
------------------------
A     36     L    
A     34     X    
B     43     L    
C     -      -
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc89e/1)

Comment: The extra type isn't really necessary. You can use the a built-in type for that: `table(sys.odcivarchar2list ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))`

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use a driver table that has all the values you want returned in it ie:

```
col1
A
B
C
D
E
```

Then `LEFT JOIN` to your table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM driver d
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
 ON d.col1 = t.col1
WHERE d.col1 in ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an extra nested table type  as in Nicholas Krasnov's answer or don't want to create a separate temporary table with A,B,C rows then  just create a driving table with `with` clause:

```
with driving_table(col) AS
(
  select 'A' from dual
  union 
  select 'B' from dual
  union
  select 'C' from dual

)
select dt.col            as col1
     , nvl(to_char(t.col2), '-') as col2
     , nvl(col3, '-')            as col3
  from Table1 t
 right join driving_table dt
  on (t.col1 = dt.col)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/112ef/2