# Displaying a value if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

I have a weather station that sends the windspeed and direction to a mysql database. I am trying to display a rose chart but for that I need the data displayed in a specific format.

I have the follow query:

```
select windspeed/10,wind_dir from weather
where windspeed/10 < 0.5
and
date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Which returns:

```
 windspeed      wind_dir
  0.4           nne
  0.1           ese
  0.2           e
  0.2           sw
  0.7           w
  1.0           ssw
```

In order to display the data properly I need to show the wind direction for entries that aren't present, ie 0 for n, 0 for se, 0 for ne etc

So

```
windspeed      wind_dir
  0.4           nne
  0.1           ese
  0.2           e
  0.2           sw
  0.7           w
  1.0           ssw
  0             se
  0             ne
  0             n
```

etc etc for all the other wind directions.

Is this possible do to in a mysql query?

Comment: If `windspeed/10 < 0.5` is your where clause then how the results with 1.0 and 0.7 need to be shown

Comment: that is just one of the queries, i have another query for speeds from  0.5 to 2 and 2 to 4, 4 to 6, and greater than 6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display record even if it doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967133/display-record-even-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: i think you should try creating a table with `id`,`wind_dir`, put all the possible values of `wind_dir` and then run your query against that table JOINING with your data table where `a.wind_dir = b.wind_dir`

Comment: I think that might do the trick.. Let me try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(w1.wind_dir) AS dir, IFNULL(ws/10,0) AS speed FROM weather w1 LEFT JOIN (
select windspeed as ws, wind_dir as wd from weather w2 
    where w2.windspeed/10 < 0.5
      and w2.date>=NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY
) wth ON w1.wind_dir=wd;
```

This will require that each wind direction exist at least once in the table.

This works by first finding all distinct wind_dir values in the table. It then left joins those results with those where the date is within 1 day to ensure that all distinct wind directions are included. Finally, it swaps any null values for windspeed with 0 because missing records will show up with a null windspeed (ws) value.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this works in your scenario:

```
select ifnull(windspeed/10,0),wind_dir from weather
where windspeed/10 < 0.5
or windspeed = 0
and date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: i think `windspeed = 0` is already qualified by `windspeed/10 < 0.5`

Comment: Getting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select ifnull(windspeed/10,0),wind_dir from weather
where windspeed/10 < 0.5
o' at line 6

Comment: @Greg give a space between `ifnull` `if null`

Comment: The thing is the values of zero for the wind speeds do not exist in the table.  The weather station only  updates the table with the current direction and speed

Comment: Tried if null: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select if null(windspeed/10,0),wind_dir from weather
where windspeed/10 < 0.5
' at line 6

Comment: @Greg do you have any indication in your table based on which you can say that windspeed is null, as far as i get your question, I take it that if windspeed = 0 no record is inserted to db in that case you can pad zeros only if you know the exact intervals after which an entry is made

Comment: @pronox: there should not be any space between `ifnull`. And @Greg looks like this error is due to something else. Can you please create a SQL Fiddle with sample data so that we can check.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is what I guess could be a solution:

Take out wind_direction to a new table and make a FK relationship with weather

Fill in all the directions possible like n,e,s,w,ne,nw,se,sw

Left join weather table with the wind_direction.

Here is sample query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(wind_speed/10,0),wind_direction 
FROM wind_direction wd
LEFT JOIN weather w ON w.wind_direction_id=wd.id 
WHERE windspeed/10 < 0.5
AND date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it working. I've created a table wind_direction with a column called direction which contains all the directions. Then tried to use the above but I still dont see the null values.